# Cron job doesn't seem to be executing in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a script located `/myscript/script.sh` and I have a cronjob that I submitted like this:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

The contents of the crontab are as follows:

```
*/1 * * * * ./myscript/script.sh
```

The script requires root privileges as it deletes directories.  Is there anything glaringly wrong with the way I've done this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest problem is that you put `.` in front of the script name. `.` is the current directory, which you are blindly assuming you know when you set up the `crontab` entry. Bottom line, don't use relative paths in `cron` scripts: give the *absolute path* to the script.

Also, `*/1` is pointlessly verbose. It means exactly the same thing as `*`. Your script runs every minute of every day. (Does it really need to run so often?)

Comment: Couple of things I should have mentioned..  The `*/1` is for testing purposes, the script will actually run every 10 mins.  Second, the `.` in the directory was a typo.

Comment: So in my cron job I don't need to run the job by preceding it with a `.` as long as my script is executable?

Comment: @nkon: I'm not talking about the dot in `.script.sh`, I mean `./myscript`. That says there is a directory underneath wherever `cron` happens to be when it starts your script called `myscript`. What directory is `cron` `cd`'d into when it runs that line? Doubtless there is a known answer, but you shouldn't care. Give the full path to the `myscript` directory here. If it's `/root/myscript/script.sh`, then say that.

Comment: All of your suggestions solved my problems.  Thanks again!